# Using fabric-client-sdk, unable to make grpc call to multiple peers

Tags: java, docker, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

By using [fabric-sdk-java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) client I am trying to invoke chaincode installed and instantiated in peers on my [Hyperledger fabric V1.0 network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) setup locally in **Windows 7** using **docker images**. I am able to invoke and query the chain code to the peer **peer0.org1.example.com**, but when I am trying the same to the peer **peer0.org2.example.com** getting the following error

```
2017-09-13 13:22:45,382 main ERROR Channel:2241 - Sending proposal to peer0.org2.example.com failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel closed while performing protocol negotiation, cause=null}
java.lang.Exception: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Channel closed while performing protocol negotiation
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:2241)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposal(Channel.java:2155)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendTransactionProposal(Channel.java:2089)
    at com.ibs.blockchain.client.utility.BlockChainUtility.sendProposal(BlockChainUtility.java:232)
    at com.ibs.blockchain.client.utility.BlockChainUtility.createFlight(BlockChainUtility.java:80)
    at com.ibs.blockchain.client.test.BCAPITest.main(BCAPITest.java:9)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Channel closed while performing protocol negotiation
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:427)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:419)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$100(ClientCallImpl.java:60)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:493)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:422)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:525)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Looking into the **docker-compose.yaml** the port mapping is like

```
peer0.org1.example.com  
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053

peer0.org2.example.com    
        ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
```

it is working only with peer having the port same as tcp port(**7051**) but getting the above error with the peer having different port **8051**. why?

Comment: Please clarify the question. In the 8051:7051 notation, 8051 is the "outside" reachable port and 7051 is the matching port inside the docker image. Also, the "UNAVAILABLE: Channel" error seems to suggest you have a typo in the fabric channel name that the peers have joined somewhere, please double-check?.

Comment: Oh you are correct. I was using the port on left side(7051) instead of "outside" reachable port you mentioned. Issue was with my understanding.:) Now its working after replacing 7051 with the "outside" reachable port. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @Bertrand_Szoghy please add this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify the question. In the 8051:7051 notation, 8051 is the "outside" reachable port and 7051 is the matching port inside the docker image. Also, the "UNAVAILABLE: Channel" error seems to suggest you have a typo in the fabric channel name that the peers have joined somewhere, please double-check?.

Comment: It was using the port on left side(7051) instead of "outside" reachable port as mentioned. Now its working fine.